# Error disconnecting server in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is only a small problem but something that irritates me to no end.
Also I wasn't sure if it would be better here or in another stack exchange?

If a server is shut down or I disconnect from a network while still having a server connected in SSMS, how then can I remove it without restarting SSMS?

[image: Server]

If I click on `Disconnect` then I get an unhandled exception:

[image: Error]

Is there any way to remove the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is an SSMS bug. A similar thing still happens in most SSMS versions, it's just that you get a -1 error in the results pane, rather then an exception

Did you patch your client tools too? The rule of thumb is to always apply service packs and hotfixes to your client tool installations too

Comment: I have 2008 R2 SP1, is this the latest revision? I have an MSDN subscription, should I try upgrading to SSMS 2012?

Comment: Is SP1 applied to the client tools?

Comment: I assumed so but now I'm not sure, how can I check?